# Curl timeout issue

Tags: php, curl

Using PHP's Curl how do I know that the page is not responding so as to grab another one?

Comment: Set timeout as strager responded, check return code of curl_exec, and you can also retreive some usefull information by curl_getinfo()

Comment: When the result array had it's `errno` key set to `28`. Just like this: `["errno"]=>int(28)`

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

```
// Wait two seconds before bailing
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
```

There's also `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`, which works for an entire request call (including DNS fetching and reading the data).

To check if a call did time out, you may be able to check its return value.  If not, the CURL handler's [`curl_errno`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) is set, which you can compare to `CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT` (or just `CURLE_OK`).

Comment: But this is not his question, is it? The question is how to tell a call timed out (as opposed to some other error)

Comment: @Pekka, Oh, seems I misread the question.  I'll update my answer.